# Python Array printing

Tags: python

```
def testCheat():
    current = 1
    msg = ['I',' ','L','o','v','e',' ','L','o','l','i','s','!'] #message
    while a == 1:
        if current <= 13:
            print(msg[current])
            current+1
        if current == 14:
            current = 1
```

testCheat()

The problem is this.

I and a friend (currently in discord call working on random stuff) are messing around attempting to work on mostly pointless code.
After the following, It Only prints Black spaces. Could someone explain why? Im  bit of an idiot right now and its 12 AM so...Yea..Usually Im not this dumb but oh well

I just need a fix for the issue..In fact Im pretty sure this is completely  wrong but It is pretty much cleaner then the stuff he made:

def loopSpin():

```
while a == 1:
    print(" ")
time.sleep(0.1)
    clear()
    print("L")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    clear()
    print("Lo")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    clear()
    print("Lol")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    clear()
    print("Loli")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    clear()
    print("Lolis")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    clear()
    print("Lolis f")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    clear()
    print("Lolis fo")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    clear()
    print("Lolis for")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    clear()
    print("Lolis for l")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    clear()
    print("Lolis for li")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    clear()
    print("Lolis for lif")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    clear()
    print("Lolis for life")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    clear()
    print("Lolis for life!")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    clear()
    print("Lolis for life!!")
    time.sleep(1)
    clear()
```

Comment: Wrong, ```current = 1```. Must be ```a=0```. I think you want to quit the loop

Comment: We do what it to loop, (Animated words) In fact thats the point if it. For example another thing we were working on was a spinning load animation, However I will try your fix and see if it works (a is external from the function and it equals 1)

Comment: There is a small syntax error in `current+1`, I think you mean `current += 1`. You don't assign the incremented value back, so you always print the `1`st element of the list which is a blank space. And for your second code I don't know what `clear()` does but you may be looking for `print('Lol for li', end='\r')` instead.

Comment: Thanks I will make that change and see how it works out!

Comment: After Making your change umutto, I am glad to say it prints, However Now it gives the error:   IndexError: list index out of range                                              It also prints onto separate lines, but I am pretty sure I can fix that issue myself! the clear() function is used to clearn the terminal. The code fo that is as follows: clear = lambda: os.system('cls') The issue doesn't lie there in any case.

Comment: Clear() is the following: clear = lambda: os.system('cls')                                     Its simply used to clear the terminal.

Comment: Use ```current < 13``` not ```current <= 13```. Also, you must adjust It  on the Next line, use 13, not 14

Comment: Yeah I just realized and was going to add, your list has 13 items. So it will give you an `IndexError` if you try to get `message[13]`. Which you do since your if clause is checking for `greater and equal`. You should change it to `current < 13` or `current <= 12` or better yet `current < len(message)`. You need to adjust the next if accordingly as well.

Comment: Thanks again Umutto, I will make the change and get back to you

Comment: I just noticed another issue I made was the following: For print(msg[current]) That would only print a single letter(Current letter) however we wanted the the current and all from before so I believe simply changing it to print(msg[:current]) would fix this?

Comment: Yup that would fix it, but in that case you need to use the old (`greater or equal`) if statement  `current <= 13` or `current <= len(msg)` since you are slicing the list this time. Also `msg[:current]` will print an ugly looking list. You may want to use `"".join(msg[:current])` to make it prettier.

Comment: Yea just noticed the ugly list look and was just about to ask about that thank you! I just fixed issues with clearing(added the clear() to it where needed) and also timing between clears Thank you for the help!